# C++ globally overloaded operator=

Tags: c++, operators, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “operator = must be a non-static member” mean? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871264/what-does-operator-must-be-a-non-static-member-mean-c)

Hi,

I have the following code...

```
// Header file
  struct dataRecord{
     size_t id;
     char name[gcNameLength];
  };

  void operator=(dataRecord &adr, const dataRecord &bdr);
```

How ever gcc gives me the following error when compiling.

```
error: ‘void operator=(dataRecord&, const dataRecord&)’ must be a nonstatic member function
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "must be a nonstatic member function" - what's not clear here?

Comment: The error message is telling the problem very precisely in this case: if you're going to overload `operator=`, you can't do it as a global function -- you have to use a non-static member function (the usual reason to use a global is to allow conversions on the left operand, but that wouldn't apply in the case of assignment anyway).

Comment: So it must be part of the struct can not be global.

Comment: Part of the error message says it all- **must be a nonstatic member function**.

Answer (score 5):

You need to overload `=` operation on the `struct dataRecord` itself.

Something like:

```
struct dataRecord{
   size_t id;
   char name[gcNameLength];
   dataRecord& operator= (const dataRecord&) {
       // write overload code here
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not such a thing as an operator= function. The operator has to be a member of the class or struct. The argument for that function is taken as the rvalue. The object with the member function is the lvalue.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [What does “operator = must be a non-static member” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871264/what-does-operator-must-be-a-non-static-member-mean-c), the operator overload needs to be a member function.

Note that when you overload the operator=, you should return a reference to the left operand, so it won't break the flow and will allow expressios like:

```
dataRecord r1;
dataRecord r2;
...
dataRecord r3 = r2 = r1;
```

Comment: I don't mind returning void from operator=. Especially if it is expensive to copy. I know the general expected behavior would be to return a reference but this has to be measured against usage costs.

Comment: Returning a reference isn't expensive. If the function is inline, most compilers will optimize it and will be free.