# c++ assignment operator helper

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to write a helper .h file with some operators.

Mainly something like this

```
QVector3D &operator=(const someDataObj&data){
      QVector3D out(data[0],data[10],data[12]);
      return out;
}
```

But when ever I try it I get : 
error C2801: 'operator =' must be a non-static member

if I try :

```
Vector3D operator=(QVector3D &left, const someDataObj &other) {}
```

I get : error C2801: 'operator =' must be a non-static member

I'm just lost... how can I properly do it ?

Edit: I forgot to mention, its main usage will be converting of data from libraryA to libraryB.

Comment: Look here: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037156/c-globally-overloaded-operator 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871264/what-does-operator-must-be-a-non-static-member-mean

Comment: Supposing you can modify the class someDataObj you can define in it a conversion to _QVector3D_ or add a method `void set(QVector3D &left);`

Comment: Sadly I don't have control over either data classes. Its a conversion from libraryA to libraryB

Comment: Make it a non-static member?

Comment: How can I do this? I mean, I'm here asking for it because I don't know how to do it...

Comment: @Dariusz You can't. End of story. Which is a good thing, because implicit conversions are a pain in the attic.

Comment: @Dariusz so you can just define a function setting a _QVector3D_ from a _someDataObj_ and call it rather than using an assignment

Comment: So esentially:
```QVector3D toQtVec(const someDataObj &other){return QVector3D(other[1],other[4],other[5]);}``` ?

Comment: @Dariusz for instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message explains, assignment operator can only be defined as a **member**. Assuming `QVector3D` comes from [Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector3d.html) and is therefore not modifiable by you, and, on the other hand, `someDataObj` is of a type you've defined, you can make a [conversion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307876/how-do-conversion-operators-work-in-c) for that type, instead. If that's not the case, then you have to perform the conversion explicitly via a non-member function.

**Edit:**

The syntax `library_a_data = library_b_data`, but one of those types must be wrapped in your own:

1. `private` inheritance

   ```
   class MyVector3D : private QVector3D // do not allow implicit conversions
   // to the base class for safety, as the destructor is not virtual
   {
   public:
       using QVector3D::member_1;
       using QVector3D::member_n; // very tedious work of bringing the names back

       // hurray, you can define your assignment or conversion operator
   };
   ```
2. composition

   ```
   class MyVector3D
   {
       QVector3D m_data;

   public:
       auto member_1() { return m_data.member_1(); }
       auto member_n() { return m_data.member_n(); } // even more tedious

       // hurray, you can define your assignment or conversion operator
   };
   ```

However, I think that **this kind of conversion should be left explicit**, but the above code should be already discouraging enough. Can we consider this as an improvement, since at one point you have to convert to your type? I don't think so.

Comment: Hey, I don't have control over either of the data classes. I'm basically converting data from libraryA to libraryB. So if I have to do "conversion explicitly via a non-member function"
Does it mean I have to write ```static QVector3D toQtVec(const someDataObj &other){return QVector3D(other[1],other[4],other[5]);}```
?

Comment: Not sure actually, I guess I need it as inline if its header only. Else I'll get duplicate declarations error I think

Comment: Programming by guessing doesn't work. [Study and learn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648) instead.