# How can I implement an assignment operator in a class template?`

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, g++

I thought my problem was answered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/871264/32836), but I can't get the following to compile:

```
#include <string>

template<class C>
class tKeySet {
  protected:
    bool set;
    static const std::string key;
};

template<class C, typename T>
class tKeySetType : private tKeySet<C> {
  protected:
    T m_val;
};

template<class C>
class tKeySetString: private tKeySetType<C, std::string> {
  public:
    tKeySetString<C>& operator=(const std::string &str) {
        this->set = true;
        this->m_val = str;
        return *this;
    }
};

class foo : private tKeySetString<foo> { };
template<> const std::string tKeySet<foo>::key = "foo key";

int main(void) {
    foo f;

    f = std::string("foo");

    return 0;
}
```

How can I make the assignment operator in `tKeySetString<C>` work with `std::string`?

Comment: `using tKeySetString::operator=;`

Comment: why are you using `private` inheritance ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I'm inheriting from concrete classes that don't have virtual deconstructors.  I thought "private inheritance" would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` **privately** inherits from `tKeySetString<foo>`, which means that `operator=` will not be part of its public interface.

You can bring it in by writing

```
public:
    using tKeySetString::operator=;
```

in the definition of `foo`.

Comment: Changing all the inheritances to `public` _doesn't appear to work_ with what I've shown above, only the `using ...` portion of the answer works.  Is there a way to avoid having to explicitly write `using ...` in all the instantiated templates?

Comment: @Jamie: sorry, that was wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9161741/598696 for a reason.